# Box inside google maps

Tags: html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've been searching an answer to this and the best i could find was here at stackoverflow, where someone explains how to insert a box of information inside the Google Maps but actually i would like to have that box side-by-side with my location.

Here is an example, just click at one of the green dots in the map, it will show you what i would like to have:

http://www.leroymerlin.pt/Site/Lojas.aspx

How can i do this? It even zooms in automatically! Wow, Google maps API V3 seems to be pretty awesome. This is cool too: goo.gl/WDMYmz . Not related though..

Thank you very much for all the help provided.

Answer (score 1):

What you see there is a [custom  overlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/customoverlays) , a implementation of the [OverlayView-class](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en&csw=1#OverlayView)

There are libraries for a convenient creation of such overlays, e.g. [infobox](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/docs/reference.html). The  zoom may be set via the `setZoom`-method of the map.

Comment: i am achieving the same result using Google API V3. Thank you for your answer